# Change the LodestoneDimension NBT tag from a compass not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a waypoint system with compass on 20w21a.
I gave to me a compass with this :

```
/give @p compass{waypoint: 1, LodestoneTracked: 1b, LodestonePos:{X : 0, Y: 0, Z: 0}, LodestoneDimension: ""}
```

And after I'm trying to modify the `LodestoneDimension` to match the dimension with this :

```
/data modify entity @p Inventory[{tag: {waypoint: 1}}].LodestoneDimension set from entity @p Dimension
```

But I'm getting this error : `Unable to modify player data`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The issue is exactly what the game tells you. You cannot modify player NBT. Workaround: `/replaceitem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Player NBT can't be modified because the game doesn't allow that. The /replaceitem is an exception to this rule but that won't be of much use to you since you need to get the current Dimension. You could make it so that you have to throw the compass onto a block and then modify the data like this:

```
/data modify entity @e[type=minecraft:item,limit=1,sort=nearest,nbt={Item:{tag:{waypoint:1}}}] Item.tag.LodestoneDimension set from entity @p Dimension
```

Comment: Okay I see, I'll try it, thanks !